# Cannot control how often fsck is running on /boot/efi

Tags: boot, fsck, fat32

Every boot `fsck` is checking the partition `/efi/boot`. I can control how often it runs on other partitions using `tune2fs` but it won't work with this partition.

### /var/log/syslog reports

```
Nov 28 19:59:55 alien systemd-fsck[612]: fsck.fat 3.0.28 (2015-05-16)
Nov 28 19:59:55 alien systemd-fsck[612]: /dev/nvme0n1p2: 239 files, 33140/97280 clusters
```

### listing of partitions

```
$ lsdrv
NAME        FSTYPE LABEL            MOUNTPOINT   SIZE MODEL
sda                                            931.5G HGST HTS721010A9
├─sda4      ntfs   WINRETOOLS                    450M 
├─sda2                                           128M 
├─sda5      ntfs   Image                        11.4G 
├─sda3      ntfs   HGST_Win10       /mnt/d       919G 
└─sda1      vfat   ESP                           500M 
nvme0n1                                          477G Samsung SSD 960 PRO 512GB 
├─nvme0n1p5 ext4   NVMe_Ubuntu_16.0 /           44.6G 
├─nvme0n1p3                                       16M 
├─nvme0n1p1 ntfs                                 450M 
├─nvme0n1p6 swap   Linux Swap       [SWAP]       7.9G 
├─nvme0n1p4 ntfs   NVMe_Win10       /mnt/c     414.9G 
├─nvme0n1p2 vfat                    /boot/efi     99M 
└─nvme0n1p7 ntfs   Shared_WSL+Linux /mnt/e         9G
```

### tune2fs refuses to work on /boot/efi

```
$ sudo tune2fs -l /dev/nvme0n1p2
tune2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
tune2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/nvme0n1p2
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

**How can I prevent `fsck` running every boot on /boot/efi?**

Comment: `tune2fs` is a tool for ext2/3/4 filesystems. Obviously it won't work on other filesystems.

Comment: @muru Indeed. It's like a `tunefsck` app is needed which is file system agnostic. Alternatively I could write a script that checks `tune2fs` next `fsck` run and flips the `/etc/fstab` byte every 50 days or whenever it runs on `/`.

Answer (score 1):

### Edit /etc/fstab

The only way I found is to update `/etc/fstab` and change the flag to never check the partition which is in `vfat` format:

Look for this line:

```
UUID=D656-F2A8  /boot/efi   vfat    defaults    0   1
```

and change it to this:

```
UUID=D656-F2A8  /boot/efi   vfat    defaults    0   0
```

The last column was set to `1` run `fsck` and we changed it to `0` don't run `fsck`.